# vim: deleting non-matching lines in command line

Tags: linux, parsing, vim, command-line

I'm using `vim` to parse a file in the command line (I'm running gentoo linux):

One of the commands is not working as [I think] it should:

```
vim -c "v/pattern/d | wq" file
```

For some reason, this is not deleting the lines without the specified pattern when adding `| wq`. If I open the file with `vim` and run the same command, it works. If I run it in the command line without `| wq` it works.

Why is this not working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that Vim sees this as `:v/pattern/(d | wq)`, see `:help :bar` for an explanation. To avoid this, either wrap the `:v` in `:execute`:

```
vim -c "exe 'v/pattern/d' | wq" file
```

or, simpler, submit this as two separate commands:

```
vim -c "v/pattern/d" -c "wq"  file
```

PS: Of course, @Bogdan has a point; you don't need Vim for that simple a task.

Comment: Thanks. There are a few other things I am doing with the file that i am using vim for and it seemed easier to keep it all together.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use **sed** for that:

```
sed -i '/pattern/d' ./file
```

Comment: While this is a good solution for deleting the lines with pattern, my specific problem is with deleting all lines *without* pattern. And while I'm sure that is possible with `sed`, I am not familiar with `sed`.

Comment: `sed -i '/pattern/!d' ./file`

Comment: @ILostMySpoon Thanks. BTW, your username gave me a laugh.